# XSLT split address on line break

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have one XML with an address like this:

```
<ADDRESS>SHIPPING ADDRESS 1
SHIPPING ADDRESS 2
SHIPPING ADDRESS 3</ADDRESS>
```

and I need to convert it to:

```
<ADDRESS1>SHIPPING ADDRESS 1</ADDRESS1>
<ADDRESS2>SHIPPING ADDRESS 2</ADDRESS2>
```

(ignore third line).

NOTE: I am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm new to XSLT and unsure of the answer. It is being called by a C# application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the first two lines, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="ADDRESS">
    <ADDRESS1>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '&#10;')" />
    </ADDRESS1>
    <ADDRESS2>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&#10;'), '&#10;')" />    
    </ADDRESS2>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes there are at least three lines. Otherwise it gets a bit more complicated. For example, you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="ADDRESS">
    <xsl:variable name="address" select="concat(., '&#10;&#10;')" />
    <ADDRESS1>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($address, '&#10;')" />
    </ADDRESS1>
    <ADDRESS2>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($address, '&#10;'), '&#10;')" /> 
    </ADDRESS2>
</xsl:template>
```

to create two address lines no matter how many lines the source address has.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer that works for any number of lines:

```
  <xsl:template match="ADDRESS">
    <xsl:call-template name="splitAddress">
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="splitAddress">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="AddrNo" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>


  <xsl:when test="$AddrNo = 2">
    <xsl:element name="ADDRESS{$AddrNo}">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:when>


      <xsl:when test="contains($string, '&#10;')">
        <xsl:element name="ADDRESS{$AddrNo}">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="splitAddress">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&#10;')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="AddrNo" select="$AddrNo + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="ADDRESS{$AddrNo}">
          <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

--Edit--
I missed the requirement to stop after the second address line.  I've inserted the `xsl:when` above to end the processing as required: the condition here can be edited as required.

Comment: This does not ignore the third line as requested by OP.

Comment: Done: apologies for missing that.  I think it's better to have an editable stop condition using xsl:when (which I've separated onto its own line for readability) just in case you need to change the requirement later.